# Flutter waiting for devices

Tags: android, flutter

today I start download flutter but I can't use any commands in the Windows cmd. When I write `flutter doctor` or `flutter`, I get `< waiting for any device >` always.

Flutter is installed in `C:/flutter` and I add flutter to PATH

Also I check if my device have a problem and with the `adb device` command I get my devices.

On Android Studio I can't create a project because of this error but with the normal Android Java Project I see my device

Every flutter command not work

flutter doctor
flutter doctor -v
flutter create my_project
flutter help
nothing

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all of the install instructions correctly?
Try adding your flutter directory to your PATH.

Comment: Yes I install Flutter correctly. I use the flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows tutorial and already add flutter to PATH

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to change the location of your flutter installation to a directory where admin privileges are not required, such as your `directory` or on your user `home` directory.

You are putting it directly in the `C:` which is completely wrong .

Don't forget to change the `PATH`

Good Luck

Comment: I try to change the directory to my Desktop and also I cant' start flutter. Also when I start the cmd with admin privileges

Comment: remove the old entry from PATH variable then add add the new location of the flutter sdk, e.g `C:/Users/<YOUR-USER>/development/flutter/bin`